# How to find all variables from expressionengine website?

Tags: php, expressionengine

I've never worked with expressionengine before but am working on a code base I didn't write and am finding some variables being injected into some of the templates using curly braces, e.g. `{embed:page}`

I want to explore these variables and ideally get the full list of the ones I can access.

Searching for `embed=` across the app returns no results relating to my example (although it does obtain some results), so it seems that some variables are being retrieved or defined in a different way.

Any idea how I can explore this via logging or other means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you'll have an overarching template (e.g. "**template_group/template_a**" including another template (e.g. "**template_group/template_b**") with the ***embed*** tag and passing through a parameter called page, so something like this in **template_a**:

```
{embed="template_group/template_b" page="12345"}
```

and within the **template_b**, you'll have access to 12345 using **{embed:page}** so if you're searching you'll probably have more joy searching for "page=" rather than "embed=" (although your "page=" will be within an "embed=" tag).

Answer (score 0):

Expressionengine tags are all curly braces.  Some are snippets, some are global variables, some are embeds, some are add-ons/extensions etc.  You have a long day of reading ahead of you:  https://docs.expressionengine.com/

Maybe https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/templates/embedding.html

Answer (score 0):

Basically everything between (exp:channel:entries}{/exp:channel:entries} are fields where data is stored.
They can be named anything the developer wants. Field groups are attached to channels. You can find all field groups by going to admin>channel administration > channel fields.
{embed} behaves in different ways. If you have a tag that looks like this {embed="foo/bar"} it is embedding a template within the current template.
When the embed tag is formed like this: {embed="foo/bar" the_entry_id="{entry_id}"} the embed is embedding another template, and passing variables from the channel:entries loop to that template. In the template these variables are called with another embed tag: {embed:the_entry_id}